# Cosmos DB emulator on IIS

Tags: iis, teamcity, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi, emulation

For testing asp.net core webapi we need a Cosmos DB connection. We cannot use docker image, unfortunately. Is it possible to deploy a Cosmos DB emulator using IIS in a Teamcity build pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the .MSI file for the emulator on the build server either manually or using PowerShell.